# New to Ubuntu Server, which logs to monitor and what to do

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh

I have been running Ubuntu Server for about four months and I learn something new everyday.  Today I learned that there are many logs that i didnt know existed.  When I examined these logs I was blown away.  For example auth.log listed what I think are hacking attempts and failed ssh login attempts from many IP addresses.

My question is this.  I am running Apache and I am connecting with ssh.  What logs should I be most familiar with in order to monitor failed login attempts and what can I do to make ssh more secure and still be able to manage my server with it?

Also, I have noticed a crazy amount of traffic at two different times when no one should have been connected to the server (using vnstat -l), but still havent figured out why. Where can I get started tracking this down.

I realize this is many questions packed into one and i apologize for that.  I still a little stunned at what I have discovered so far.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/55679/ubuntu-server-ssh for more on `ssh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you look at the `logcheck`-package - it monitors most (if not all) relevant logs and sends you hourly summaries of any and all suspect entries. Note it sends e-mail, so you have to set up a server for that too...

As to failed SSH logins, I suggest you look at using a firewall to block all access by unknown hosts - try looking at Ubuntu's "Uncomplicated FireWall", `ufw`.

Finally, I suggest you go look at the official [Ubuntu Server Guide](http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/).

(For good measure, I usually install these on all servers; `munin` for monitoring, `backupninja` (name says all), `etckeeper` for keeping track of `/etc` and, as mentioned, `logcheck`.)

Comment: Thank you. I have been strictly Windows admin until recently, when I decided to test drive Ubuntu Server and I really like it, but I obviously have a lot to learn.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: do you recommend something for email?  i use blat on my windows machines.  Is there something comparable?  Thanks again.

Comment: Have a look at `esmtp` by José Fonseca.

Comment: Dennis thanks for answering my question-in-a-question

Answer (score 4):

I'd tend to use logwatch, rather than logcheck (although, that's a matter of taste more than anything). For securing ssh, I'd start by installing fail2ban, which will block those who continually fail to login. I wouldn't bother changing the ssh port, it's still trivial to find, due to ssh's connection string, and is really more trouble than it is a benefit. Also, you should forbid root logins over ssh, by changing PermitRootLogins in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to 'no'.

I can't tell you how to track down previous large amounts of traffic, but netstat/lsof -i would give you lists of connections, which may help if you see it again.

Comment: +1 for 'forbid root logins over ssh' I cant beleive I havent done that yet....

Comment: "I'd start by installing fail2ban, which will block those who continually fail to login." Fail2Ban and the likes do NOT increase security, only reduce log spam.

Comment: How does fail2ban not increase security? It makes brute forcing ssh pretty much impossible. That may not be a large issue, but it is a possibility.

Comment: @The Pixel Developer eh, wtf? Fail2ban on ubuntu will by default begin to drop ssh from addreses after 6 auth failures. Since this makes a brute force attack *MUCH* harder i'd say this is a pretty big security benefit.

Comment: I would agree on logwatch. Tools that email you like logwatch, apticron etc., are useful for very small numbers of servers. When it sends more email then you're bothered to read regularly then it's time to look into something smarter.